# Why is print not a function in python?

Tags: python

Why is `print` a keyword in python and not a function?

Comment: see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

Comment: interesting; never considered it a problem but good question.

Comment: readln and writeln were built-ins in Turbo Pascal as well. Never understood why, and I liked C better for making them functions instead.

Comment: @JFSebastian: That explains, why a print function would be better. But not, why it wasn't one in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because Guido has decided that he made a mistake. :)

It has since been corrected: try Python 3, which dedicates a [section of its release notes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) to describing the change to a function.

For the whole background, see [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) and the several links provided in its References section!

Comment: I havent tinkered with Python 3 yet. Does the print keyword still work?

Comment: No. It's a function now. In the simple case, `print "foo"` becomes `print("foo")`

Comment: Corrected as in "now a function" :)

Comment: @steffen — I have added a direct link to the PEP, and fixed the name of the first link to make clearer that I am linking directly to the release notes explanation of the change.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes: My confusion is rather due to the acceptance of your answer as the correct one by the OP than your answer itself. I tend to agree with you that it was a mistake in the first place and has been corrected in Python3. But the original question was _why_ `print` was made a statement in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

`print` **was** a statement in Python because it was a statement in ABC, the main inspiration for Python (although it was called `WRITE` there). That in turn probably had a statement instead of a function as it was a teaching language and as such inspired by basic. Python on the other hand, turned out to be more than a teaching language (although it's good for that too).

However, nowadays `print` **is** a function. Yes, in Python 2 as well, you can do

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and you are all set. Works since Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

It is now a function in Python 3.

Comment: @user: It's not necessarily a matter of time so much as a matter of compatibility, both forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` statement in Python 2.x has some special syntax which would not be available for an ordinary function.  For example you can use a trailing `,` to suppress the output of a final newline or you  can use `>>` to redirect the output to a file.  But all this wasn't convincing enough even to Guido van Rossum himself to keep it a statement -- he turned `print` into a function in Python 3.x.

Comment: Uhhh, now this is starting to make sense.

Comment: So the additional functionality is lost now though? Such as the trailing , and >>

Comment: It's still there, but now you use the `end=` and `file=` keyword parameters instead of the special syntax.

Answer (score 1):

An answer that draws from what I appreciate about the `print` statement, but not necessarily from the official Python history...

Python is, to some extent, a *scripting language*.  Now, there are lots of definitions of "scripting language", but the one I'll use here is:  a language designed for efficient use of short or interactive programs.  Such languages tend to allow one-line programs without excessive boilerplate; make keyboard input easier (for instance, by avoiding excessive punctuation); and provide built-in syntax for common tasks (convenience at the possible expense of purity).  In Python's case, printing a value is a very common thing to do, especially in interactive mode.  Requiring `print` to be a function seems unnecessarily inconvenient here.  There's a significantly lower risk of error with the special syntax that does the right thing 99% of the time.

Comment: By this argument `input` would need to be a statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will throw in my thoughts on this:

In Python 2.x `print` is not a statement by mistake, or because printing to `stdout` is such a basic thing to do. Everything else is so thought-through or has at least understandable reasons that a mistake of that order would seem odd. If communicating with `stdout` would have been cosidered so basic, communicating with `stdin` would have to be just as important, yet `input()` is a function.

If you look at the [list of reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and the [list of statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) which are not expressions, `print` clearly stands out which is another hint that there must be very specific reasons.

I think `print` *had* to be a statement and not an expression, to avoid a security breach in `input()`. Remember that `input()` in Python2 evaluates whatever the user types into `stdin`. If the user typed `print a` and `a` holds a list of all passwords, that would be quiet catastrophic.

Apparently, the ability of `input()` to evaluate expressions was considered more important than `print` being a normal built-in function.