# Pycharm: How to set a breakpoint when something writes to console (stderr)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm using Pycharm on a Debian machine to write a Python application which uses multiprocessing.

During execution I get sometimes messages like

```
/proc/XXX: No such file or Directory
```

I cannot explain myself where those errors come from.

Therefore I would like to know if it's possible to set a conditional breakpoint.
This breakpoint should be active when something writes to stderr and the error message appears in the console log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Adding a datetime stamp to Python print](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4883789/95735) to see how to *overwrite* `write` method. You have to use `sys.stderr` in place of `sys.stdout` of course. When you overwrite `write` method this way you can set breakpoint in the new `write` method.